# Getting Windows Instance ID in AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Hello there I am running a Windows instance in AWS 
however I want to retrieve the "instance id" using powershell or python.
I am referring to this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

but I can't make it to work

the reason is that I have this DB of all instance ID and I need to check the instance ID in the database to and execute some code in different instances below is the pseudo code

```
//check if the instane ID is in the DB
if(instanece_id is in DB){
 //perfore the action for that instance

}else{
 //print error message
}
```

I also try this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2InstanceMetadata.html

```
Get-EC2InstanceMetadata -Category AmiId
Get-EC2InstanceMetadata -Category InstanceId
```

but  didn't return any results

Comment: [EC2: Get-EC2InstanceMetadata Cmdlet | AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2InstanceMetadata.html)

Comment: I have tried this it works but it doesn't print anything

Comment: Did you try the provided examples to see whether _they_ work? If they worked, but your command for `InstanceId` did not work, then please edit your Question to show the command you used.

Comment: I made it to work I relaunch an instance thanks the last instance I have somehow don't have an id